# Как в woocommerce изменить label в форме заказа?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно изменить в форме заказа label для одного из полей, делаю я это через код в functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false; // Адрес

    return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields',90 );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Номер отделения Новой Почты'; 
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = ' '; 

    return $fields;
}
```

**При обновлении страницы текст меняется на нужный, но через долю секунды меняется на стандартный.**
 Возможно  дело в приоритетах? 
На данный момент решил вопрос через замену перевода:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');
function translate_text($translated) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Название улицы', 'Номер отделения Новой Почты', $translated);

    return $translated;
}
```

Работает , но я не уверен в правильности решения

Comment: У вас несколько языков?

Comment: wordpress ставил на английском , потом пришлось поменять на русский ,  а потом  на английский

Comment: В данном случае фильтр вы сделали правильно, просто затем подтягивается нужный перевод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подмена перевода для меня отлично сработала

```
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');
function translate_text($translated) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Название улицы', 'Номер отделения Новой Почты', $translated);

    return $translated;
}
```